# Get column's max value from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

The output below is a pretty printed snapshot of a portion of a dictionary that I am trying to work with.  I'm looking to output the highest value of all entries in column `p`, as well as it's main dictionary key.

In the example output below, the value for `p` in `GRTEUR` is higher than any other values of `p` from any of the other main keys so I would like to return the main key and the value, so `GRTEUR` and `-0.1752234098475558`.

I've read about Pandas and using `pandas.DataFrame.max()` but I'm not finding any examples on how to evaluate the values from a key (`p`) of a nested dictionary (`1h`).

Any pointers?

```
data = {
    "LUNAEUR": {
        "1h": {
            "ot": "2021-07-09 08:00:00",
            "o": 6.033,
            "h": 6.551,
            "l": 5.983,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 08:59:59.999000",
            "p": -1.660459342023591
        },
        "stream0": {
            "c": 6.444,
            "v": 1393.808,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 09:59:59.999000"
        },
        "stream1": {
            "c": 6.446,
            "v": 1171.177,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 09:59:59.999000"
        }
    },
    "THETAEUR": {
        "1h": {
            "ot": "2021-07-09 08:00:00",
            "o": 4.992,
            "h": 5.076,
            "l": 4.956,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 08:59:59.999000",
            "p": -0.2963841138114934
        },
        "stream0": {
            "c": 5.061,
            "v": 492.138,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 09:59:59.999000"
        },
        "stream1": {
            "c": 5.067,
            "v": 423.079,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 09:59:59.999000"
        }
    },
    "GRTEUR": {
        "1h": {
            "ot": "2021-07-09 08:00:00",
            "o": 0.5616,
            "h": 0.5717,
            "l": 0.5523,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 08:59:59.999000",
            "p": -0.1752234098475558
        },
        "stream0": {
            "c": 0.5707,
            "v": 105.17,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 09:59:59.999000"
        },
        "stream1": {
            "c": 0.571,
            "v": 19.71,
            "ct": "2021-07-09 09:59:59.999000"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that you want the `max` but in your example you say that the lowest value is the one you are after? Do you mean the max `abs` value? How are you reading this dictionary into pandas?

Comment: You are right, @Alex  `max` for `p` in that output would be `GRTEUR`.  My eyeballing was wrong.

I'm using things like `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data, ...)` or `pandas.DataFrame.max(data, ...)` to get that into pandas.

Comment: Updated question to fix my bad eyeballing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the data using python `max(..., key=...)`:

```
key, value = max(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["1h"]["p"])
print(key, value["1h"]["p"])
```

To ignore those keys whose values don't contain the "p", you could either provide a very small default value

```
import sys
max(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["1h"].get("p", -sys.float_info.max))
```

or filter before finding the max:

```
max(((key, val) for key, val in data.items() if "p" in val["1h"]),
    key=lambda x: x[1]["1h"]["p"])
```

Comment: this seems very simple, but getting `KeyError: 'p'`.  H ave a feeling that this is because `data` is dynamically generated so not all keys/values, like `p`, are necessarily going to be present the time the function needs to be called.

I tried to workaround that by putting your sample into a `try:` but it always hits the exception, even when there are other items in `data` that do have `p` present, which this function should present:

```
def display(data):
    try:
        key,value = max(data.items(), key=lambda x: abs(x[1][rtf]['p']))
    except:
        print("Fail")
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if "p" doesn't exist? Should they be ignored?

Comment: @mcsonini Your pre-filter example is perfect, thank you.  After looking at the results, I could actually do with seeing top N max results.  I believe `max()` supports the single max only though, so I'd need to look elsewhere for top N max?

Comment: you can use sorted with the same key function and select the maximum amount you need, e.g. `sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["1h"].get("p", -sys.float_info.max))[-2:]`, or analogously with the pre-filtered version

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function gives the values of nested keys in each dictionary. Maybe you could try this:

```
def deep_get(dictionary, *keys):
  print(keys)
  return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key, None) if isinstance(d, dict) else None, keys, dictionary)

val_list=[]
key_list=["LUNAEUR","THETAEUR","GRTEUR"]
for item in key_list:
  key1=item
  key2='1h'
  key3='p'
  print(deep_get(data, key1,key2,key3))
  val_list.append(deep_get(data, key1,key2,key3))
  print(max(val_list)

Output:
-0.1752234098475558
```